# Searching for idiom frequency list

Tags: idioms

I am looking for a list of the most common idioms in Japanese, and ideally I want the list to be frequency-based. In other words, it should be based on a large corpus.

Comment: I don't have an answer, but I want to provide some context. Because they are often composed of words which may not always appear sequentially or can be conjugated, counting idiom frequency is a nontrivial NLP problem. I wanted this data (along with phrasal verb frequency) in English and couldn't find it; I can't find it for Japanese either with a cursory Google search. There are plenty of articles talking about common idioms if you're willing to give up on hard numbers, though.

Comment: Yes I suspected it would not be an easy task, for precisely the reason you mentioned. I've seen articles and books containing 'common' idioms, but often I've found that real Japanese people don't actually use many of these. That's why I was hoping to find a list which was backed up with statistical data. But if you have some good links, I'd be happy to receive them :)